# OpenIndiana ZFS with shareiscsi property missing

Tags: solaris, iscsi, zfs, openindiana

I'm trying to present a ZFS file system as an iSCSI target. This is ultimately for using it with OS X Time Machine, but that should be irrelevant in this question.

```
# zfs get all | grep scsi
```

From several blog posts, it appears it should have a "shareiscsi" property. But just to be thorough, I installed the iscsi target package, hoping it would show up:

```
# pkg install pkg:/network/iscsi/target
# svcadm enable -rs network/iscsi/target
# svcs | grep scsi
online         Mar_30   svc:/network/iscsi/initiator:default
online          6:02:56 svc:/network/iscsi/target:default
```

Still no shareiscsi in the properties. I did see a [blog post](http://www.kamiogi.net/Kamiogi/Frame_Dragging/Entries/2009/5/25_OpenSolaris_ZFS_iSCSI_Time_Machine_in_20_Minutes_or_Less.html) about having to install "SUNWiscsitgt" but according to pkg, it is obsolete:

```
# pkg info -r SUNWiscsitgt
Name: SUNWiscsitgt
State: Not installed (Obsolete)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears OpenIndiana does not use the shareiscsi property. Also (perhaps relatedly) COMSTAR is not included as part of the base installation. So I fired up a fresh OpenIndiana VM and ran the following commands and was able to create, share and mount a sparse LUN without any drama:

```
sudo -s
pkg install network/iscsi/target
svcadm enable -s stmf
svcadm enable -s iscsi/target
zfs create -o mountpoint=none rpool/iscsi
zfs create -V 8G -s rpool/iscsi/yourmom
sbdadm create-lu /dev/zvol/rdsk/rpool/iscsi/yourmom
sbdadm list-lu
```

Use that GUID from the sbdadm output (my GUID below):

```
stmfadm add-view 600144f096c28d0000004dbeb9df0001
itadm create-target
itadm list-target
```

Take your target name (example: iqn.1986-03.com.sun:02:9f57392e-9859-61fe-ec5c-da681f9214dd) and put it in to your iSCSI initiator (I use the free [globalSAN iSCSI](http://www.snsftp.com/public/globalsan/) on my mac) along with the IP address (or hostname) of your OpenIndiana box. Tada.

Source: [Setting up COMSTAR and iSCSI target](http://nexenta.org/projects/site/wiki/SettingISCSI) on the Nexenta Wiki.

Comment: I wish I could double plus one for "yourmom".

Comment: Oracle Solaris 11 doesn't seem to support shareiscsi either. These directions did work for me though.

Too bad it's not as straightforward as the previous zfs goodness.